# Show update status cell above UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Several apps including the Facebook App shows an update-cell when the table is moved to the top. How is this implemented?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Note that this sucks with VoiceOver. I know someone who's blind, and using this UI is impossible for him. Unless your app is focused on visual things (e.g. pictures), don't do this.

Comment: @WTP That seems like a fairly sweeping statement. The space saved it very advantageous for people who are not visually impaired. However the space saved is not relevant for the visually impaired. Perhaps a better solution would be to detect if accessibility is on (I can't see how in the docs, a user pref may have to be used) and cater the experience accordingly. More importantly it is an issue that is normally completely forgotten about e.g. unfortunately it didn't cross my mind until you mentioned it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do what you need, https://github.com/chpwn/PullToRefreshView, it's quite easy to implement

Comment: Thank you. This revision helped me making it work on my UITableView: https://gist.github.com/1611706.

Answer (score 1):

There are many different solutions here's one [PullToRefresh](https://github.com/leah/PullToRefresh).

The problem I noticed (with this one at least) is that it is expected that you are subclassing `UITableViewController` which is not always the case